# Django migrations does not set default values for Inlinepanel id

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, wagtail

I used PostgreSQL with Django,currently i can't insert values to any inline panels in my project because, it throws **null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint** 
but it works correctly for two days before

**Not working table**

```
  Column     |          Type          | Modifiers

--------------+-----------------------+-----------

 id           | integer                | not null
```

**Expected behaviour**

```
 Column      |           Type           |                         Modifiers

-----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------

 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('highlights_id_seq'::regclass)
```

**Highlights model**

```
    class HighLights(models.Model):
        highlights_link = models.ForeignKey(
            'wagtailcore.Page',
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            related_name='+'
        )

        panels = [
            FieldPanel('highlights_link', classname="full"),
        ]

        class Meta:
            abstract = True
   class HomeHighLightsOfMonth(Orderable, HighLights):
        page = ParentalKey('Main', related_name='high_lights')
```

**Main** is my parent class where i can add my inline panel

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: now u can check my code @Usman Maqbool

Comment: Can you show what you've tried when you got this error?

Comment: please update your question with code when you try to save record in DB and you are getting error.